# How to customize unattended-upgrades notification emails?

Tags: unattended-upgrades

Is there any way to customize the unattended-upgrades results mail in ubuntu?

The current configuration in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` file -

```
// Send email to this address for problems or packages upgrades
// If empty or unset then no email is sent, make sure that you 
// have a working mail setup on your system. The package 'mailx'
// must be installed or anything that provides /usr/bin/mail.
//Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "root@localhost";
```

sends an email on every run. Instead, I would like to customize it to send only on error. Is there any way I can configure that?

Answer (score 9):

Don't know why they deleted this line on Ubuntu, but Debian includes:

```
// Set this value to "true" to get emails only on errors. Default
// is to always send a mail if Unattended-Upgrade::Mail is set
//Unattended-Upgrade::MailOnlyOnError "true";
```

If your `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` don't include the line (and the [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/u/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades_0.79.3ubuntu4/changelog) don't give away this change in presice) is very odd, but at least it doesn't say they changed the behavior. I use a slightly updated version (0.80~sid2 opposed to 0.79.3ubuntu4 that Ubuntu includes in the precise-updates repository) and it will send a mail only on errors (I hasn't get a mail for now). Just write the lines to your configuration file, and everything should be working:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "your@email.com";
Unattended-Upgrade::MailOnlyOnError "true";
```

You may want to run `sudo unattended-upgrade -v -d --dry-run` to check the entire process yourself.

Comment: Ubuntu (at least some versions) seem to ignore this line: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unattended-upgrades/+bug/1056104

Comment: In 14.04 LTS, the line `Unattended-Upgrade::MailOnlyOnError "true";` is back in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`. It's commented out by default.

Comment: note that multiple addresses can be used as well with:
`Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "root,someuser,your@email.com,others@somewhere.com";`

Comment: Newer versions of unattended-upgrade no longer email if `--dry-run` is specified

Comment: Indeed, how do we test this now?

Comment: How does the unattended upgrades send out the email? Do I need to setup any emailing software on the server?

Comment: @xyz it sends using sendmail. Whatever provides sendmail does it.

Comment: To add some more context here, I got the following in my logs which explains which providers it tries: ERROR No /usr/bin/mail or /usr/sbin/sendmail, can not send mail. You probably want to install the mailx package.

Answer (score 1):

Works as of Linux Mint 20 which is pretty much Ubuntu 20.04.
To quote the comments in the file

> Set this value to one of:
> "always", "only-on-error" or "on-change"
> If this is not set, then any legacy MailOnlyOnError (boolean) value
> is used to chose between "only-on-error" and "on-change"

```
Unattended-Upgrade::MailReport "only-on-error";
```